# How to include team name of selected player in tellraw

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to display a tellraw message which includes the team name of a selected player.

Example:  A player on *Red* team has reached x score!

Something like {"selector":"@p"} but instead of displaying player's name, I want it to display the player's team name.

Comment: What is your situation and what is your desired output? For example I don't understand what you mean with "select a team".

Comment: @Fabian I think something like {"selector":"@p"} but instead of displaying player name,I want it to display a team...

Comment: @Denelio I have tried to use testfor @p[**team=Red**,score_tmp_min=x] and a comparator pointing at a command block `/tellraw @p [{"selector":"@p[score_tmp_min=5]"},{"text":" in Red Team now have "},{"score":{"name":"@p[score_tmp_min=5]","objective":"tmp"}},{"text":" points"}]`)but if there are soooooooo many teams(like 100teams or something),It will be impossible to make it...

Comment: @RaymondLiu1 It's not an answer to your question so I didn't post it as an answer, but some suggestions on your comment.  Skip the `testfor` command, use a command like `execute @a[team=Red,score_tmp_min=x] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a [{"selector":"@s"},{"text":" in Red Team now have "},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"tmp"}‌​},{"text":" points"}]`.  Also, when using more then one command block, use chain conditional blocks, instead of a comparator to another command block.  I understand not wanting to have to build an iteration per team though.

Comment: There is a finite amount of team colours (16 or so), so you would only need 16 command blocks. Does that work for you?